# Enable browser zoom only on one part of the website (like google maps)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I want to be able to have effect on my website like google maps. The top bar the side bars, I don't want them to change at all, whether using normal scroolwheel or ctrl + scrollwheel.

However, the central part I want to be able to zoom in/out like pretty much google maps
, just by using scrollwheel. How do I achieve this?

It's for the angular app that I'm building. Also is using canvas better for this zoom effects?

Comment: Yes, you must use the canvas. Google disable the scroll wheel zoom by default and handle a set of variables to make the zoom effect.

Comment: @jtwalters Okay. Will go with canvas solution. But do you have more info on those variables? Some tutorial? Would appreciate it!

Comment: @jtwalters No... you definitely *don't* need to use a canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can install a `$('#container').on('wheel', zoomContainer)` handler that uses a transform with scale to resize the container. The native JavaScript equivalent handler is: `document.querySelector('#container').onwheel = zoomContainer;`

Here is a proof of concept. I have not figured out though how to crop the container on zoom.

```js
let scale = 1;
function zoomContainer(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if(event.originalEvent.deltaY !== 0) {
    if(event.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
      // wheeled up
      scale += 0.1;
    } else {
      // wheeled down
      if(scale > 0.2) {
        scale -= 0.1;
      }
    }
    $('#wrapper').css({transform: 'scale(' + scale+')'});
  }
}

$('#container').on('wheel', zoomContainer);
```

```css
#page {
  width: 500px;
}
#header, #footer, #leftSide, #rightSide {
  border: 1px gray solid;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}
#leftSide {
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
}
#rightSide {
  float: right;
  height: 200px;
}
#wrapper {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page">
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div>
<div id="leftSide" style="float: left;">Left Sidebar</div>
<div id="rightSide" style="float: right;">Right Sidebar</div>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="container">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br /><br />
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.<br /><br />
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.<br /><br />
</div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Similarly you could implement panning using a transform with translate.

Comment: Will definitely try . In the snippet it pretty much looks what I need. However I would need first to figure out te jQuery inside Angular. From what I've seen, it's not a simple thing to do.

Comment: No need for jQuery, I posted the native JS wheel event. You'd need to convert the jQuery selectors in the function to native JS as well.